# How to set DigestMethod to Sha 256 WCF?

Tags: algorithm, wcf, security, sha

I'm writing a client using WCF and I need to set the signaturemethod algorithm to rsa-sha1 and the DigestMethod to sha256.  None of the enum values in the SecurityAlgorithmSuite support this.
So, I want this in my SOAP request:

```
   <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
   <ds:Reference URI="#TS-25">
   <ds:Transforms>
   <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
   </ds:Transform>
   </ds:Transforms>
   <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
```

My code:

```
    Dim asbe As System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
    asbe = New System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement

    asbe.MessageSecurityVersion = _
        MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11

    asbe.InitiatorTokenParameters = New System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters(System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Thumbprint, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient)
    asbe.RecipientTokenParameters = New System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters(System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.Thumbprint, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator)


    asbe.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt

    asbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict
    asbe.EnableUnsecuredResponse = True 
    asbe.IncludeTimestamp = True 
    asbe.SetKeyDerivation(False)

    asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256Rsa15

    Dim usernameToken As New UserNameSecurityTokenParameters
    usernameToken.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient
    asbe.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(usernameToken)
    asbe.AllowInsecureTransport = True

    Dim myBinding As CustomBinding
    myBinding = New CustomBinding

    myBinding.Elements.Add(asbe)
    myBinding.Elements.Add(New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8))

    Dim httpsBindingElement As HttpsTransportBindingElement  
    httpsBindingElement = New HttpsTransportBindingElement
    myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement)

    Return myBinding
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you have to create a custom class that inherits SecurityAlgorithmSuite. You can then set the Default properties on the overrideable methods to whatever you need. To use it, instead of:

```
asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Sha256Rsa15
```

you would do:

```
asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = new CustomAlgorithmSuiteclass
```

then your DefaultAlgorithmSuite property on the proxy object will contain all of the defaults set in the custom class.
I didn't figure this out credit goes to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b149878-f9a2-44e3-afd4-68884b02e129/algorithm-suite-wcf-ws-security