# WCF, MessageSecurityException when processing response: The Basic256Sha256 algorithm suite does not support for the 'Digest' operation

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler

I am using a WCF client generated in c# and I use a http sniffer (fiddler) for showing the communication that seems to be okay (http 200):

[image]

However it seems there is a problem when WCF parses the message:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The Basic256Sha256 algorithm suite does not support the 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1' algorithm for the 'Digest' operation.

[image]

This is my servicemodel config:

[image]

Does anybody have a clue about how can I specify WCF in order to parse manually the part that is not working in order to get more info?

Thank you in advance.

(sorry about my English, I have no one to practice my English but this page... )

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877960/how-to-set-digestmethod-to-sha-256-wcf) for help.